# Denormalization - maintaining redundancy by using triggers in Oracle

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracle11g

I have a task for my university project where I have denormalized a table and now I have to implement a trigger in order to maintain redundancy. After following the book accordingly I'm stuck on the last step and I can't get my mind around it.
I have two tables - Supplier and Catalogue

`**Supplier**
SupplierCode (primary key)
SupplierName
**Catalogue**
SupplierCode (foreign key)
CatalogueCode (both SupplierCode and CatalogueCode form a primary key)
CatalogueName
DateCreated
SupplierName (redundant column for denorm purposes)`

When a new row is inserted in the Catalogue table I want that SupplierName field in the same table gets populated based on the SupplierCode which was inserted.

What I have so far:
We need to create a package as well

```
create or replace PACKAGE "PACK" AS 
SUPPCODE NUMBER:=0;
SUPPNAME VARCHAR2(50);
END;
```

I have created a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER on Catalogue table

```
create or replace TRIGGER CatalogueBefore
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON CATALOGUE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
PACK.SUPPCODE:=:NEW.SUPPLIERCODE;
END;
```

I've then added an AFTER INSERT TRIGGER on Catalogue table

```
create or replace TRIGGER "AddNewCatalogue"
AFTER INSERT ON CATALOGUE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
V_SUPPNAME SUPPLIER.SUPPLIERNAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT SUPPLIERNAME INTO V_SUPPNAME
FROM SUPPLIER
WHERE SUPPLIERCODE= PACK.SUPPCODE;
PACK.SUPPNAME:=V_SUPPNAME;
END;
```

After all of this I have the Supplier name held in my package in PACK.SUPPNAME but my question is how do I now use this variable when inserting a new row in the Catalogue table? I'm stuck at this for some time now and I'm probably missing something obvious. :) Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

P.S Please ignore uppercase vs. lowercase letters - I've just translated the names from my native language. :)

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Congratulations to have take time to translate the various names. Some comments though: why do you feel the need to use a package variable to store the supplier code ? What would append if there was an insert with several `SUPPLIERCODE` for each rows ? In addition, what would append in case of concurrent update of your table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have denormalized a table and now I have to implement a trigger in order to maintain redundancy
>
> [...]
>
> When a new row is inserted in the Catalogue table I want that SupplierName field in the same table gets populated based on the SupplierCode which was inserted.

If those are your only requirements, all you need is *one* trigger to alter the record with the data from the second table. Something like that, maybe:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CatalogueBefore
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Catalogue
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT S.SupplierCode INTO :NEW.SupplierCode
    FROM Supplier S
    WHERE S.SupplierName = :NEW.SupplierName;
END;
```

That way, on update or insert into the table `Catalogue`, the `SupplierCode` will be overwritten by the code coming from `Supplier` table. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d79e0/1 for a live example.

Some notes though:

- For this to work, `Supplier.SupplierName` *should* be an unique index too. In fact, the all thing is based on the assumption this is a [natural key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key).
- You very probably need an other trigger to deal with updates in the `Supplier` table. Say, when one supplier's name will change, the new name will have to be propagated to `Catalogue`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer Sylvain. I think this is not working. When inserting a new row I don't want to pass the SupplierName value I just want to e.g insert a SupplierCode and CatalogueCode into the Catalogue table. I guess the purpose of the package is to learn about the package and the example that I've outlined here follows the analogy of the examples which I have in my book. I've already created a trigger which will change the values of SupplierName in Catalogue table if the SupplierName changes in the original table Suppliers.

Comment: So something like this.... INSERT INTO Catalogue (SupplierCode,CatalogueCode,Something) VALUES (2,332,'WinterCollection'); - after this statement I want the field  SupplierName in the Catalogue table to be populated with e.g. "IBM" which is listed under SupplierCode 2 in the Supplier table. Hope this doesn't sound too confusing. :) Thanks

Comment: @Wizard ... so, if I understand it well, you just have to swap `SupplierName` and `SupplierCode` in the trigger. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ce7f4/1

Comment: Hi Sylvain, this works! Thank you very much. Not sure why they make us use packages in the book I was probably deluded by that and missed the obvious thing. I've created two more triggers - one for changes of Supplier name in the Supplier table and one that forbids changes of Supplier name in the Catalogue table. Once again, thanks. ;)